# How can I test JavaScript output in the DOM without a browser?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom

I would like to test the output generated by some functions which are responsible to generate new content in the dom.
The problem is that I need to test such scenarios without using a browser and by running xpath queries against the generated output. (something like HTMLUnit in Java).
How can I write such tests? Which framework/technology can I use?

Comment: This is what you need http://phantomjs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually handled by using a browser running on a fake screen (e.g. using [xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)) and driving it programmatically. [Headless](https://npmjs.org/package/headless) will let you set up xvfb from within node.js.

[Phantom](http://phantomjs.org/) and [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) provide a couple of ways to drive browsers.